# Cannot access my web server from the Internet (with forwarded ports and firewall exceptions)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, webserver

I'm trying to run my custom publicly visible web server.

I've created dummy one using windows IIS running on port 25226 (random number).

On 'server' machine `localhost:25226` or `10.0.0.4:25226` gives correct homepage.

Using `10.0.0.4:25226` on other device in local network also works.

Server has fixed ip `10.0.0.4`

I've added Inbound and Outbound rule to windows firewall to allow port `25226`

I've forwarded port `25226` to `10.0.0.4`[image]

When trying connect to `mypublicip:25226` I get an error. `mypublicip` is obtained at any "whatismyip" page

When I go on any online port checker page (like http://canyouseeme.org/) and check port `25226`, it is closed.

I've even tried to enable DMZ Host to `10.0.0.4` and even turned windows firewall off.

What can I do to make it work? How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was trying to connect from company network, which has blocked most of the ports. Everything was setup right on the server side. Changing the port was the solution